# How to delete spacing between my card in react Native (FlatList)?

Tags: css, react-native, masonry

As you can see, I want to display my items in masonry. But the existing packages so far don't let me to do it with different types of card.

This is my flatlist. The "PiinsStandard" could be videos, pictures or posts.

```
            <FlatList
                numColumns={2}
                style={styles.list}
                data={this.props.PiinsFeed.piins}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (<PiinsStandard piins={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />)}
                onScroll={this._onScroll}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                onEndReached={() => this._getPiinsList()}
            />
```

This is my style for each card

```
    card: {
        marginVertical: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 4,
        borderRadius: 8,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
        elevation: 5,
        flex: 1,
    }
```

[image]

Thank you if you have the solution. I already tried this package : https://github.com/brh55/react-native-masonry but it's impossible to custom my card like I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [react-native FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns), items should all be the same height - masonry layouts are not supported.

So in order to achieve a masonry layout, you have to use custom library.

- [@appandflow/masonry-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@appandflow/masonry-list) allows creating masonry-style list layouts in a performant way.
- [react-native-masonry-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-masonry-list) which supports the masonry layout for images.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much I found the solution with @appandflow/masonry-list